# Windows AD user impersonation in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to deploy a website to Azure App Services. I have a identity impersonation in my web.config to access image server.

```
<system.web>
   <identity impersonate="true" userName="sroy" password="abc123"/>
</system.web>
```

I am getting error "Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect.'"

Is there any way to fix this?
Is there any way to impersonate a AD user, so that it can connect the image server and grab the images?

Comment: I imagine the server would need to be domain-joined for this to work. You can't domain-join App Service instances.

Answer (score 3):

As juunas mentioned, your app service is not on your domain, so that will not work. If the image server is on premise you will need to find a different way to handle authentication. If the image server is in Azure, then you can give the website a [Service Principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) that it can use to log in to other resouces without embedding a user's credentials.